# AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function:

Tags: python-3.x, flask

Tengo la siguiente situación: estoy haciendo un registro de usuario con python en flask y me esta presentado el siguiente error:

Gracias

**Error:**

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/yoel/curso-python/todoer/venv/bin/flask", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/yoel/curso-python/todoer/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 1054, in main
    cli.main()
  File "/home/yoel/curso-python/todoer/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1055, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/yoel/curso-python/todoer/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1657, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/home/yoel/curso-python/todoer/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1404, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/home/yoel/curso-python/todoer/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 760, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/yoel/curso-python/todoer/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 84, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/yoel/curso-python/todoer/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 760, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/yoel/curso-python/todoer/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 918, in run_command
    raise e from None
  File "/home/yoel/curso-python/todoer/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 904, in run_command
    app = info.load_app()
  File "/home/yoel/curso-python/todoer/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 308, in load_app
    app = locate_app(import_name, name)
  File "/home/yoel/curso-python/todoer/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 235, in locate_app
    return find_best_app(module)
  File "/home/yoel/curso-python/todoer/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 63, in find_best_app
    app = app_factory()
  File "/home/yoel/curso-python/todoer/todo/__init__.py", line 22, in create_app
    app.register_blueprint(auth.bp)
  File "/home/yoel/curso-python/todoer/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/scaffold.py", line 50, in wrapper_func
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/yoel/curso-python/todoer/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1296, in register_blueprint
    blueprint.register(self, options)
  File "/home/yoel/curso-python/todoer/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/blueprints.py", line 439, in register
    deferred(state)
  File "/home/yoel/curso-python/todoer/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/blueprints.py", line 491, in <lambda>
    lambda s: s.add_url_rule(
  File "/home/yoel/curso-python/todoer/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/blueprints.py", line 112, in add_url_rule
    self.app.add_url_rule(
  File "/home/yoel/curso-python/todoer/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/scaffold.py", line 50, in wrapper_func
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/yoel/curso-python/todoer/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1358, in add_url_rule
    raise AssertionError(
AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function: auth.register
```

**Función**

```
bp = Blueprint('auth',__name__, url_prefix='/auth')

#Función para el registro del usuario
@bp.route('/register', methods=['GET','POST'])
def register():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        db, c =  get_db()
        error = None
        c.execute(
            'select id from usuer where username = %s'
        )
        if not username:
            error = 'EL usuario es requerido'
        if not password:
            error = 'EL password es requerido'
        elif c.fetchone() is not None:
            error = 'El usuarioa () se encuentra registrado,'.format(username)
        if error is None:
            c.execute(
                'insert intro user (username,password)value(%s,%s)',
                (username, generate_password_hash(password))
            )
            c.commit()

            return redirect(url_for('auth.login'))

        flash(error)

    return render_template('auth/register.html')
```

Comment: Al parecer ya tienes otra ruta así. El error dice que no puedes tener 2 rutas iguales

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por la respuesta y si el problema lo tenia en la segunda ruta que tenia en el script